# FileUpload return false for HasFile property when I have 2 submit buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `FileUpload` button and 2 `Submit` buttons. The first one, called `Confirm` and just show me a page with all data that I put in my form just to confirm is it's OK. The second one, called `Save`, save those data in my database.

The problem is that when I click in `Confirm` button, the `FileUpload` returns `true` to `HasFile` property, but in the second button, the same operation return `false` to `HasFile`.

What can I do to fix it ?

**Code**

```
public void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
          // Many validations here
    }
}

public void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Always return false here
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
          // Many validations here
    }
}
```

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentConteudo" runat="server">
   <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Formulario">
      <asp:Panel ID="pnl_form" runat="server">
         <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1" class= "span2" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
         <asp:Button ID="Confirm" CssClass="btn btn-netimoveis btn-large" runat="server"
          OnClick="Confirm_Click"  UseSubmitBehavior="false"  Text="Confirmar" />
      </asp:Panel>
 </asp:Panel>
 <asp:Panel ID="pnl_confirm" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Save" CssClass="btn btn-netimoveis btn-large" runat="server"
     Text="Incluir" OnClick="Save_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: could you post the asp.net markup code for the buttons as well?

Comment: this info doesnt seem to be enough to identify the issue. What are you doing with FileUpload1 in page load?

Comment: @Guanxi In Page Load I don't call my FileUpload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic behind FileUpload is not easy to be understood.. how the file is taken, were it's kept.
If you ignore it you can use the file when it's available!

```
public void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
          // Many validations here
          // Keep file in Session or in a temporary storage
    }
}

public void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Take the file from session or temporary storage and save it

    if (myFile != null)
    {
          // Many validations here
     }
}
```